# Prime generator in python returns multiple composites instead of primes

Tags: python, primes

I'm fairly new to Python, and am trying to practice programming by doing Project Euler problems. In order to solve the [7th problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=7), I decided to first build a simple prime generating function using for loops, which doesn't seem to work.

Here's my code:

```
primes = [2]

for n in range(2, 10):
    for m in range(2, n):
        if not(n % m):
            primes.append(n)

print primes
```

The output is `[2,4,6,6,8,8,9]` instead of what I intended, i.e. `[2,3,5,7]`. The math seems correct to me: Pick a natural number, `n`, bigger than two. For all natural numbers m bigger than one, but smaller than `n`, check if `n` is divisible by `m`. If not, add n to the list of primes. Can anyone please tell me what's wrong with my code?

P.S. While I know there are several other (and better) ways of generating primes, I am interested in making my approach (code) work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`not(n % m)` tells you if a number is *not* prime.

You also need to do it for every candidate factor before you know if the number is prime or not.

Python has a very handy mechanism for this in `for: else:`, which only runs the `else` block if you did not break from the `for`.

```
primes = []
for n in range(2, 10):
    for m in range(2, n):
        if not(n % m):
            break
    else:
        primes.append(n)
```

You can test primality in a similar way with a generator expression:

```
prime = not(any(n % m == 0 for m in range(2, n)))
```

Remember `range` is inefficient in Python 2.x, as it generates the entire list of numbers before starting iteration. Use `xrange` unless you're on Python 3.x

Comment: I added the break and else statements, according to your suggestion, and got [2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 9] as an output. Do you know why it returns 5 and 7 multiple times?

Comment: Did you put the else at the wrong depth? That's not the output I get when running the exact code I submitted.

Comment: Yes, that was my mistake. I incorrectly assumed that the else statement should be on the same depth as the if statement. Thanks again!